# Ubuntu MAAS with Juju

Tags: juju, maas

I have a doubt about juju.

Do we have to install Juju on the ubuntu server or ubuntu desktop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify this question? It's not obvious what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juju on Ubuntu

To install Juju, you simply need to grab the latest juju-core package from the PPA:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core

or read more here

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started

hope this helps

Comment: That is to say, it does not matter if you are installing on server or desktop.  You can install on either.  The MaaS server, where you run juju, does not seem to get hit real hard, except when you are initially  provisioning your cluster from juju, and then it is all network IO, pushing the OS and charms out to the nodes, not CPU load.